# Separation of logics (Restructuring of project)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm building a web api project and planning to separate data access layer and domain layer to separate projects. The project and its associated type should be as follows :

```
Web - API Project (ASP Net 5 Web Application)
Data Access Layer (ASP Net 5 Class LIbrary)
Domain Layer (ASP Net 5 Class LIbrary)
```

**Question :** Since the class libraries do not have Startup class how can I used the db connection set in my web API project to the other projects?

**Note :** Web API is referencing to the DAL and domain

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow good architecture,

```
1. Web API Project
2. Framework /Core Models
3. Business/Domain Library
4. Data Library
```

so define your IDataProvider/IDatabase in Framework which is shared library to web api, business and data library, you can use IOC/Dependency injection to your Data Library

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/808894/IoC-in-ASP-NET-MVC-using-Autofac
for reference

Answer (score 0):

What you suggested is good, the only this i would recommend is that data access can be setup to connect to the database, but since it would be utilized in the API so you need to make sure that all configs (including connection strings and keys) have been set in the web.config for the web api and not in the app.config of the class library.

Hope this helps.